# AJAX to PHP - Not displaying new data

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have a small row of images that i can click and a veriable is ajaxed over to a php file for database query.. There it recieves the veriable, and does the correct query. The problem is. instead of the HTML being updated on my page. it just echos into my console... Does anybody know why this is. my code seems legit enough...

```
<div id='smallpagination' class='smallpagination'>

<script>
function showvid(vid){
    console.log ("sent"+vid);
    var $vid = vid;

     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "smallpaginationdata.php", 
                data: {id: $vid}, 

                success: function(vid){
                    console.log(vid)
                },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("failure");
                    }
            });

};

</script>


<?php

//search according to chosen search critera NOT LIMITED//
include ("conect.php");

$startit = 0;

$startfrom=rand(0,20); 

$displayto=$startfrom+10;
$search=""; 


$startedfrom=$startfrom;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE title LIKE '%%$search%%'
LIMIT $startfrom , $displayto
";



                              // check how many results //
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 


$videos = $row['videos'];

$v_id = $row['id']; //<!---important is Video ID and needed for video click selection---->

$id = $row['id'];

$Name = $row['Name'];
if (empty($Name)) {$Name='Annonymous';}


$image = $row['image'];

$info = $row['info'];
if (empty($info)) {$info='Contact Listee (if Provided) , No Item Information Given';}

$phone = $row['phone'];
if (empty($phone)) {$phone='See Listing';}

$title = $row['title'];

$locate = $row['locate'];
if (empty($locate)) {$locate='Not Provided';}

$postcoded = $row['postcode'];
if (empty($postcoded)) {$postcoded='???';}

$price= $row['price'];
if (empty($price)) {$price='?';}
if ($price=='0') {$price='?';}

$date = $row['stamp'];
if (empty($date)) {$date='';}

if ($startit<1) {$gotid=$row['id']; $startit=$startit+1;};
    $vidd= $row['id']-0.01;
    $pidd= $row['id']-0.02;
    $type = $row['type'];
    $showinglocate=$row['id']-0.03;
    $showingphone=$row['id']-0.04;
    $displaytype="minlist";
            //Thumbnails sized listings     
            if ($displaytype=="minlist") {

            echo"
            <div class='floaterminhomepage'>
            <div class='innerfloaterminhomepage' >
            ";

            if (!empty($videos)) { 

            echo "

            <video id='$v_id' style='position:absolute;  top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; background-size: cover; object-fit:fill;' preload='metadata' onclick='showvid($v_id);'>

            <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
            <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/ogg'>
            <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/webm'>
            </video >



            "; }

            if (empty($videos) && empty($image)) { 

            echo "

            <img src='pageimages/blank.png' style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%;  width:100%; height:100%;'>
            "; }
            if (!empty($image) && empty($video))  { 

                    echo "


                    <img src='image/{$image}'  style='position:absolute;  top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; background-size: cover; object-fit:fill;'>


                    "; }
            echo "

            </div> 
            </div> 

            "; } 
};
    ?>

</div> <!---smallpagination--->

<?php

include('smallpaginationdata.php');

?>


SEND ID TO THIS PHP FILE...

<?php
include ("conect.php");

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$gotid = strip_tags($_POST['id']); 
};

echo "recieved $gotid";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata
WHERE id=$gotid;
";

 // check how many results //
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$videos = $row['videos'];
$v_id = $row['id']; //<!---important is Video ID and needed for video click selection---->
$Name = $row['Name'];
if (empty($Name)) {$Name='Annonymous';}
$image = $row['image'];
$info = $row['info'];
if (empty($info)) {$info='Contact Listee (if Provided) , No Item Information Given';}
$phone = $row['phone'];
if (empty($phone)) {$phone='See Listing';}
$title = $row['title'];
$locate = $row['locate'];
if (empty($locate)) {$locate='Not Provided';}
$postcoded = $row['postcode'];
if (empty($postcoded)) {$postcoded='???';}
$price= $row['price'];
if (empty($price)) {$price='?';}
if ($price=='0') {$price='?';}
$date = $row['stamp'];
if (empty($date)) {$date='';}
$type = $row['type'];
};


THIS IS ECHOD INTO THE CONSOLE RATHER THAN IN THE PAGE???


echo "
<div id='pointerbox' class='pointerbox'>
</div>  
    <div id='smallpagdata' class='smallpagdata'>
     <h5> {$gotid} </h5>
    <h4><u>{$title}</u></h4>
    <p style='color:crimson; margin-top:0px;'>£{$price}</p>
    {$info}

    <p style='color:crimson; margin-top:-2px;'>{$locate}</p>
    <p style='color:blue; margin-top:-20px;'>{$Name}</p>
    <p style='color:crimson; margin-top:-14px;'>{$phone}</p>

    <p style='color:green; margin-top:0px;'>Thank you for viewing</p>
    <p style='color:green; margin-top:-12px;'>Double Click image to view full listing & videos</p>
    </div>  
";
?>
```

its sends the correct ID

and recieves it.

and the correct data is displayed in my Console m, rather than updating it in the html...

Any ideas as to why..

thanks in advance.

p.s the html is allready once displayed in the html no problems, but once i onclick and send the ajax, it just echos into console??

Comment: If you never output the received data into the DOM, it's pretty...normal. Just using `console.log` will only show it in the console.

Comment: im only supposed to be console logging the recieved ceriable tho.. the html displays but is not updated. i dont get it

Comment: Do i have to do sumthing in the sucess part of the ajax to make it redisplay or summet...

Comment: Of course ! You receive the data, then you play with it. So if you wanna add it to whatever `div` with let's say `hello` id you just do `document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = vid`

Answer (score 2):

you should add the response to the div rather than using console.log inside the success function. i don't know how this is done in jquery but look it up it should be very simple.

Comment: glad to help, i'm also new to this so i know the feelings. good luck with your work

Comment: thanks,  I sussed it but iv got another issue. i used $("#smallpagdata").load("#smallpagdata"); and it reloads the div, but inside itself lol... also the ids get screwed up if i click more than once. i en up with 7 instead of 2 ect. wierd.

Comment: @russbaker2016 The argument to `.load()` should be the URL of the script, optionally followed by a selector to extract just part of the result.

Comment: @russbaker2016 `.load()` is just a shortcut for calling `$("#smallpagdata").html()` inside the success callback. It replaces the contents of the div, you'd need to use `.replaceWith()` to replace the div itself.

Comment: with jquery i really have no idea, but if you want an answer in vanilla javascript i'll be glad to give you one

Comment: ok. iv got it sort of right now, i can manage to replace the html inside the div within the ajax success , but im struggling to put php ans html into the success bit. not suew of the right syntax,